# How to compute the "15% of the time" randomness?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'm looking for a decent, elegant method of calculating this simple logic.
Right now I can't think of one, it's spinning my head.

I am required to do some action only 15% of the time.

I'm used to "50% of the time" where I just mod the milliseconds of the current time and see if it's odd or even, but I don't think that's elegant.

How would I elegantly calculate "15% of the time"?  Random number generator maybe?
Pseudo-code or any language are welcome.

Hope this is not subjective, since I'm looking for the "smartest" short-hand method of doing that.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a difference between something happening 15% of the time, and something happening randomly, with probability of .15. As you increase the number of trials, the two will presumably converge, but for a small sample, they might be quite different. Which do you want?

Comment: @joelt -- good point, which I think is the ultimate debate going on now by the answerers below, but I would like to know (@everyone) how much of a difference is it at the beginning until they converge?  How significant is it to affect the resulting algorithm?

Comment: The difference will be...random :) I've done similar things using randomness, and gotten way far away from my target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 (double)**

- get a random double between 0 and 1 (whatever language you use, there must be such a function)
- do the action only if it is smaller than 0.15

**Solution 2 (int)**

You can also achieve this by creating a random int and see if it is dividable to 6 or 7. **UPDATE** --> This is not optimal.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. There is no guarantee that the 15% of numbers are before 0.15 unless you exhaust the whole period of the generator. Sorry if I am incorrect, looking for an explanation only.

Comment: @AraK, he's not looking for an exact number of trials (e.g. 100 total, 15 `doX`).  He wouldn't get exactly half with the `% 2` he mentions in the question either.

Comment: You are correct. But the question is “15% of the time” **randomness** so we are not talking about exact here.

Comment: Thanks sir. I have no problem with this solution from a theoretical point of view, but from observation point of view the generation period is too big in most generator types.

Comment: Won't the second solution give you 6.6% probability (1 out of 15)?

Comment: @Aliostad -- I'm having a hard time comprehending the second solution.  Doesn't that translate to "divisible or not divisible" and ultimately be just "true or false", which is 50%?

Comment: Thanks Guys, you are right! It must be divisable by 6  or 7 which is not good.

Answer (score 2):

You can produce a random number between 0 and 99, and check if it's less than 15:

```
if (rnd.Next(100) < 15) ...
```

You can also reduce the numbers, as 15/100 is the same as 3/20:

```
if (rnd.Next(20) < 3) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a PRNG.  Like always, it's a performance v. accuracy trade-off.  I think making your own doing directly off the time is a waste of time (pun intended).  You'll probably get biasing effects even worse than a run of the mill linear congruential generator.

In Java, I would use [nextInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

```
myRNG.nextInt(100) < 15
```

Or (mostly) equivalently:

```
myRNG.nextInt(20) < 3
```

There are way to get a random integer in other languages (multiple ways actually, depending how accurate it has to be).

Comment: It is not saying if he is using C or C++.

Comment: @Allostat, there are equivalents to `nextInt` in both C and C++.

Comment: +1. It is important to note that most (good) PRNG solutions that offer a bounded value function take *great care* to ensure uniform distribution (this doesn't say anything about the "random" quality of the underlying PRNG, just the distribution of values within the range). At the very least, even if such details are not important, the functions are generally easy to use -- also, using "whole numbers" may add more semantic meaning to the code (which is why I would not use the 2nd solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Random number generator would give you the best randomness. Generate a random between 0 and 1, test for < 0.15.

Using the time like that isn't true random, as it's influenced by processing time. If a task takes less than 1 millisecond to run, then the next random choice will be the same one.

That said, if you do want to use the millisecond-based method, do `milliseconds % 20 < 3`.

Answer (score 0):

Using modulo arithmetic you can easily do something every Xth run like so

```
(6 will give you ruthly 15%
```

if( microtime() % 6 === ) do it

other thing:

```
if(rand(0,1) >= 0.15) do it
```

Comment: The first suggestion isn't really random nor reliable depending on how often the code is called and how often the time is updated (e.g. Windows updates some timers only every ~16 ms).

Comment: thats true. i just picked up where he left off because he said his desired with 50% would be based on milliseconds. of course its not random but nothing is really random. well, something is... but however. depends on the applicatin! if you have a website and you want to distribute ad delivery or something, microtime is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean array[100] = {true:first 15, false:rest};
shuffle(array);
while(array.size > 0)
{
    // pop first element of the array.
    if(element == true)
       do_action();
    else
       do_something_else();
}
// redo the whole thing again when no elements are left.
```

Comment: He never said he only wanted to do it (or not) 100 times.  And shuffling is O(n) every time you do it.

Comment: @Mathew Please look at my comment here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434896/how-to-compute-the-15-of-the-time-randomness/4434916#4434916 of why I think this is more practical than using random numbers directly.

Answer (score 0):

This quote is from a great [article](http://daviddeley.com/random/crandom.htm) about how to use a random number generator:

> Note: Do NOT use
>
> ```
>   y = rand()  %  M;
> ```
>
> as this focuses on the lower bits of
>   rand(). For linear congruential random
>   number generators, which rand() often
>   is, the lower bytes are much less
>   random than the higher bytes. In fact
>   the lowest bit cycles between 0 and 1.
>   Thus rand() may cycle between even and
>   odd (try it out). Note rand() does not
>   have to be a linear congruential
>   random number generator. It's
>   perfectly permissible for it to be
>   something better which does not have
>   this problem.

and it contains formulas and pseudo-code for

- r = [0,1) = {r: 0 <= r < 1} real
- x = [0,M) = {x: 0 <= x < M} real
- y = [0,M) = {y: 0 <= y < M} integer
- z =  [1,M] = {z: 1 <= z <= M} integer

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that combines randomness and a guarantee that eventually you get a positive outcome in a predictable range:

Have a target (15 in your case), a counter (initialized to 0), and a flag (initialized to false).

```
Accept a request.
If the counter is 15, reset the counter and the flag.
If the flag is true, return negative outcome.
Get a random true or false based on one of the methods described in other answers, but use a probability of 1/(15-counter). 
Increment counter
If result is true, set flag to true and return a positive outcome. Else return a negative outcome.
Accept next request
```

This means that the first request has probability of 1/15 of return positive, but by the 15th request, if no positive result has been returned, there's a probability of 1/1 of a positive result.

Comment: Wait... we're looking for 15 in 100, not 1 in 15. How would you modify your approach to do that?

Comment: Err, right. Change the flag to a success counter, which starts at zero, and runs to 15. Run the counter from zero to 100. Instead of a 1/(15-counter) probability, use (15-success)/(100-counter). Make sure you increment in the right places to get the bounds correct...